# C# Unit test that fails randomly

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

I'm working on a project that has some unit test that fails randomly when executed on Team City. And nobody can reproduce the same behavior on local machines.
As almost all tests executes the tested method inside a `TestDelegate` action and executes the `Asserts` and `Verifies` outside the actions I belive it could be a concurrency problem.

But before I do any change on test code I'd like to have more information about the execution of `TestDelegate` actions in **.Net Framework 4.0**.

This is a example of a unit test that fails randomly.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTest
{   
    private Mock<IAnyService> _anyService;
    private MyClass _myClass;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _anyService = new Mock<IAnyService>();
        _myClass.AnyService = new MyClass() { AnyService = _anyService.Object };
    }
    
    [Test]
    public void MyClass_Should_Call_MockClassMethod()
    {
        TestDelegate action = () => _myClass.MyMethod();

        Assert.DoesNotThrow(action);

        _anyService.Verify(_ => _.MockClassMethod(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

My class method

```
public override void MyMethod()
{
    ...DoALotOfStuff
    AnyService.MockClassMethod();
}
```

This is the error on Team City

> Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: _ => _.MockClassMethod()
>
> No setups configured.
>
> No invocations performed.

What could be the reason of it fails randomly?

Is possible that the action is executed in separate thread only on Team City?

EDIT:

---

I was able to do this test fail randomly using this command to execute the test.  But still don't know why.

```
nunit3-console (ls -r ./tests/**/bin/**/*.Tests.dll -exclude *.Product* | % FullName | sort-object -Unique) --teamcity --x86 --framework=v4.0
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running your tests with any of NUnit's Parallelization options enabled? I don't see any evidence of parallelization in your example code, but it could be enabled elsewhere--for example, there could be a `[Parallelizable]` attribute at the assembly level in `AssemlyInfo.cs`.

If the tests are running in parallel, it's possible that you're leaking state between tests. NUnit re-uses a single instance of a test fixture for all test methods within that fixture ([source](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/2574)). Since your mocks are are fixture-scoped, there could be a race condition between the setup and assertion logic of two tests running concurrently.

The `TestDelegate` itself doesn't look concerning to me. Calling a delegate isn't much different from calling any other method, except that you're doing it indirectly through a variable. In the example code you provided `_myClass.MyMethod()` will still run synchronously--unless you've introduced threading or concurrency elsewhere.

Edit:

Additional information provided from the question author in a comment, added here for visibility at their request:

> After looking into the documentantion [https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line] I realized that nunit-console has a parameter --agents that is used to control running the assemblies in parallel and if not specified, all agent processes run tests at the same time, whatever the number of assemblies. When I added --agents=1 on the command line all tests run successfuly.

Comment: I'v looked into my solution and ther is nothing explicit about run tests in parallel. But it make sense. Maybe the default configuration of unit tests is to run the tests in parallel. I'll search for something about it and then I'll come back with some news.

Comment: After looking into the documentantion [https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line] I realized that nunit-console has a parameter --agents that  is used to control running the assemblies in parallel and if not specified, all agent processes run tests at the same time, whatever the number of assemblies. When I added --agents=1 on the command line all tests run successfuly. Could you add this information in your answer? it may help others user in the future. Thanks for your guidance.